# In NetLogo how can I extract the x and y coordinates of a subset of turtles every nth tick?

Tags: netlogo

I have a very simple model of 50 turtles moving away from a central point. I would like to be able to extract the spatial coordinates `(xcor, ycor)` of a subset of them every nth tick in behaviour space. Hope you can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulo operator `mod` is probably the simplest way to do this. It outputs the remainder from a division operation, so you can just use a logical flag such that the coordinates are only extracted when `ticks` divided by n is equal to 0. For example:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 10
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ; set up lists for example output
  let tlist []
  let xlist []
  let ylist []

  ask turtles [
    rt random 60 - 30
    fd 1
  ]

  tick 

  ; If ticks is not zero, and the remainder of
  ; the number of ticks / 3 is zero, extract
  ; some info about the turtles and print it.
  if ticks > 0 and ticks mod 3 = 0 [
    ask turtles with [ xcor > 0 ] [
      set tlist lput self tlist
      set xlist lput xcor xlist
      set ylist lput ycor ylist
    ]
    print tlist
    print xlist
    print ylist
  ]  
end
```

Run this several times and you'll see that on `tick` 3 (and 6, 9, 12, etc), the lists are printed out. Note that where you have your `tick` increment will affect when this output is actually extracted- in the example above, `tick` happens at the end of the go procedure but before the `if` statement is evaluated.